# Can't compare Strings

Tags: spring, string, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am not able to compare the String returned from student.getUsername() to the hardcoded string(it is alway false even for correct values)
but when I use a normal string and not the one returned from student.getUsername() it is able to execute if block and return "login Success". I think the value returned from student.getUsername() is not comparable to String I even tried .toString() but no luck Please help.

```
 @PostMapping()
       public String setUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("Student")Student student, Errors errors, 
          ModelMap model) {

            String user = "das";
            String pass  = "12345";

            if((student.getUsername()==user)&&(student.getPassword()==pass))return "loginSuccess";
            else return "loginFailure"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use equals() method to compare the CONTENT of strings.
== operator in Java compares addresses of objects not theirs content :<